# How to establish MySQL connection using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to learn `JDBC` and `MySQL` , and I'm stuck at establishing connection between `JDBC` and the driver. I have already copied the driver to my project, and this is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {

    System.out.println("Connection to server...");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver").newInstance();
    System.out.println("Connection succesful");


    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But it always throws an exception. I did some research about this and it seems I need to use a `DriverManager`, but there are many code samples but no explanations. So I'd like some help understanding how is this working, I don't want to just copy and paste code.

Comment: I am sure you have not gone through JDBC theory first. Anyway you can find tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/ here. But recommend you to read theory (mostly architecture) first.

Comment: I googled for you :) http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html

Comment: "*But it always throws an exception*" you should at least add details about the exception that is throw. But I'm pretty sure if you search for the exception message together with "mysql jdbc" you'll find your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of your question

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
```

Just registers the Driver. Each JDBC driver provides a driver class which contains inormation required by the DriverManager for creating the connection to the database
Then This line

`Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "username", "password");`

makes the connection to the database

Refer [DriverManager#getConnection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Properties))

Comment: Using `Class.forName()` to register the driver is not necessary any more since Java 6 introduced the "service registry". Any current driver should register automatically.

Comment: Complete agree with you